# Canny Operation on Image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, scikit-image, x-ray

I want in the  image below to (by using Python):

1.) Find the contours of the bones (only the sides will do)

2.) Recognize and draw all the contours.

It could look something like this:

A better contour is even good. I am not entirely sure as to how I could tackle this,

The gradient of the image is:

Comment: What have you already tried? The main workflow with OpenCV is to filter the image until you have an image with well-defined features, after which recognition would be much easier.

Comment: I took a gradient of the image. Is there a way, I could use this to get the contours?

Comment: @JesuKiranSpurgen there are ways to get the contours, the difficulty is how will you distinguish the bones contours from the skin contours? Maybe you could exclude the outside contours right? Since the bones will always be inside a body?

Comment: @JoãoCartucho Yes that is correct. The problem I am facing is to come up with a logic to have the contours of the bones (shown as yellow lines). For example, for the first bone, if I want to find the perpendicular distance between the 2 contour lines.. how could i ask the python script to identify the 2 contour lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A initial way of approaching this would be using canny edge detection using the right threshold values and then find the contours.

```
import cv2

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("/home/tribta/Desktop/feet.png")

# Find the contours
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,60,200)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

hierarchy = hierarchy[0] # get the actual inner list of hierarchy descriptions

# For each contour, find the bounding rectangle and draw it
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

# Finally show the image
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Then you could add some biomedical processing criteria to distinguish the different contours and verify if it is really a bone.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply first a threshold using `cv2.threshold` to clean your images from objects you don't want to, try different values of intensity to catch the borders, then apply some morphology operation such as `OPENING` and `CLOSING` with `cv2.morphologyEx` to clean a bit the image, fill the [holes](https://www.learnopencv.com/filling-holes-in-an-image-using-opencv-python-c/) and finally applied `cv2.findContours` and `cv2.drawContours` to get the finally image of the contour of the bones.

check those command on  [opencv library](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html)
You will find really good examples on stackoverflow and internet, try adapting your code to those.
Hope this was a good help to you.

Comment: Thanks! But can you suggest if I can get the contours as seen in the picture (in yellow). Since, I would like to find the perpendicular distance between the two contours. Many thanks,

Comment: oh, I could recommend you to [skeletonize] (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html) in that page there's a good example when using medial axis, and then use segmentation to extract the piece of bone, applied some `labeling` and `regionprops` to obtain each piece and paint the columns of the boundarybox.


Another possibly solution can be applying Hough line transformation, can be a little bit tedious but sure will give you good results check this http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html